# How to automatically add fields to an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have not that much experience in javascript so I dont know how I can exdent the array automatically. Here is an example:

```
 var chart_arr = [
    {
        "x": 1325676960000,
        "y": 25500.50,
    },
    {
        "x": 1325875140000,
        "y": 30000.50,
    }
];
```

So now I want to add more fields to it. How can I achieve this?

Comment: That isn't a multi-dimensional array.  And "adding fields" is meaningless.  Are you asking how to set properties inside a loop?

Comment: just push a new object to it

Comment: Kruben, have a look at this **[documentation about the JavaScript `Array`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)** That should help you on the way.

Comment: A really great resource for language questions like this would be the Mozilla developer network: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript they have great basic tutorials as well as feature documentation. If it's not already in your bookmarks for the first place to find info on JS, then you need to add it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
chart_arr[0].z = 12345; // add a new property to an existing object
chart_arr.push({x:567, y:890}); // add a new object to the array
```

As an aside, you don't have a two-dimensional array, you have an array of objects.

Comment: Thanks, dude. I think I have demonstrate that i hadnt much knowledge about it. thanks a lot.

Comment: Not to worry.  We were all a newbie at the beginning.  Welcome to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

This is another way of doing it:

```
Object.defineProperty(chart_arr[0],"z",{ value: 1, writable:true,enumerable:true,configurable:true});
```

This defines z value as 1 into chart_arr[0].

Result:

```
chart_arr[0] -> x: 1325676960000 y: 25500.5 z: 1

chart_arr[1] -> x: 1325875140000 y: 30000.5
```